# not expected output from script

Tags: linux, bash

when i run this code with an argument e.g `./getopts -a` it prints "`hi -a"` though the expected out would be  `"hi hello"`. Any ideas whats going wrong?

```
 #!/bin/bash

while getopts a:name
do
        case $name in
          a)aopt=$OPTARG;;
          *)echo "Invalid arg";;
        esac
done

if [[ ! -z $aopt ]]; then
    echo $aopt
fi

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

#exit 0
```

Comment: ...then... what happens?

Comment: Please, what's the question?

Comment: If i run this code with an argument:

./getopts -a hi hello
it does print "hi -a".

how do i print "hi hello"

Comment: This comment should [edit] of your question post instead. (The question and its main details should be part of the question post itself, not a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

may be you are missing quotes and spaces:

```
    while getopts "a:" name; do
        echo "name=$name";
        case $name in
            a)aopt=$OPTARG;;
            *)echo "Invalid arg";;
        esac
    done
    if [[ ! -z $aopt ]]; then
        echo $aopt
    fi
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

execute via command:

./myCode "hi hello"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing being tied to your `-a` option is `hi`.  If you simply need to pull `hello` along with `-a hi` you can just pull it from the command line with $3.

```
while getopts "a:" name; do
            case $name in
                a)aopt=$OPTARG;;
                *)echo "Invalid arg";;
            esac
        done
        if [[ ! -z $aopt ]]; then
            echo "$aopt $3"
        fi
        shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

Please note the "" around what you need to echo.  I would suggest taking a look at http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt for a nice quick read on getopt.